# react native : How do I make the text label that will check the checkbox while press on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox, react-hooks

How do I make the text "BIRD" label that will check the checkbox while press on it ?
According to my example it does not work and it is not clear to me.

```js
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

function App(props) {
  const isSelected = useSelector((rootState) => rootState.BitzuaDigumReducer.checkBox);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        top: 20,
        left: 10,
      }}
    >
      <CheckBox
        value={isSelected}
        onValueChange={(value) => dispatch(setCheckBox(value))}
        style={styles.checkbox}
        tintColors={{ true: 'white', false: 'white' }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.label}>BIRD</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I mocked Checkbox on this example, but please review it. It should give you a basic idea on how to toggle checkbox value by pressing the label: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/toggle-checkbox-on-label

Core code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
    setSelected(!isSelected);
    // Here you can dispatch the event to state management
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Checkbox onValueChange={toggleCheckbox} selected={isSelected} />
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={toggleCheckbox}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>{'Label'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: can u show how u dispatch it there ? i need my example will works

Comment: @Kira24 I think you need to elaborate a bit more. What are you trying to dispatch (checkbox value?) and where (Redux?). And do you want to dispatch it on every action or only on when the (assumed) form data is posted somewhere

Comment: I need the BIRD label to mark the checkbox exactly as it is if you click on the checkbox itself and it will activate the dispatch just as it happens when you click on the checkbox itself